# Batch rename all files in folder to uppercase

Tags: windows, file-management, batch-file, rename

Is there a way to rename all files in a specific folder to uppercase?

I found this code but it renames files to lowercase, can it be modified to change to uppercase instead?

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %f in ('dir /l/b/a-d') do (rename "%f" "%f")
```

Comment: You may get a better or quicker answer on StackOverflow for this

Comment: @Sahil: This question is about Windows; the one you're referring to is about bash.

Comment: @Scott: My apologies Scott. The solution presented in the other thread was for Windows which is why I referred to it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Sahil: No need to apologize. That other question is an enigmatic mess: it's (fairly) clearly about bash, and yet the OP ***accepted*** a Windows answer. You can delete your "possible duplicate" comment (above), and, if you have any actual knowledge of the Bulk Rename Utility, you could post it as an answer, after reading [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/150988)

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever considered using powershell ?

Try this command :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path your_path -Recurse | Rename-item -NewName {$_.name.ToUpper()}
```

Of course, replace the *your_path* part by the path of your folder.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with Microsoft PowerToys PowerRename feature. It adds a context menu to bulk-rename files, including the ability to capitalise and use Regular Expression. More details can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was possible before, but you can do this with the capitalize button pressed.

[image]